# Liferay Hook - Unsupported Version

Tags: liferay

I'm having an issue with a custom hook I'm deploying in Liferay.

I've created both a hook and a theme using **Liferay Plugins SDK 6.2.0**

I create a .war (with Eclipse's built in Liferay -> SDK -> war command) for my theme, and deploy it onto my server running **Liferay EE 6.2**, which works fine.

However, I repeat the same process with my hook and I get this error:

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/bofa/UserLoginImpl : 
Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class com.bofa.UserLoginImpl)
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassL
oader.java:2908)
```

I'm not sure if this could be a Java Compiler version error like I've read about, because my theme uses the same exact settings and works properly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because of `different JDK at compile time and runtime`, make sure you are using same JDK version to compile and run it.

It generally occurs if a higher JDK version  is used to compile the java file and  a lower JDK version is used at runtime

Comment: Spot on, Gautam. Hey, that rhymes.

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, set up the Java compiler compliance level to a lower level in order to prevent that kind of mismatches in versions when compiling / running.
Properties > Java > Compiler > JDK Compliance